# Flask Validation Error 'NoneType is not iterable' from RadioField in FormList of FormFields?

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms, formfield

I'm dynamically populating a form in Flask using a FormList of FormFields but am at a loss with an error from the validation function. On this form, the user provides an entry name and then for each game queried from a database table, picks one from a RadioField and ranks their confidence in their pick 1-N. I've tested the validation with a test that was hard-coded, and I've gotten the dynamic field generation below to work, but when I try to validate the below it fails when iterating through `games-#-pick` with `'NoneType' is not iterable`.

I believe this is because the loop keeps going beyond my bounds. In my test I only have three entries in `games`, so `idx` is 0,1,2 and I should see three PickForms generated. When validate fails I see `self.name` is `games-3-pick`, so validate is checking one more FormField in my FormList than I though should have been generated.

How do I validate this? Is it an issue with the FormField validation, or how I'm dynamically `appending_entry()` to the FormList?

```
@bp.route('/pick', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pick():
    games = Game.query.order_by(Game.game_date.asc()).all()
    form = EntryForm()
    for idx, g in enumerate(games):
        form.games.append_entry()
        form.games[idx].pick.label = g.bowl_name
        form.games[idx].pick.choices = [('away', g.away), ('home', g.home)]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
       ...database writes and redirect if validated...

class PickForm(FlaskForm):
    pick =  RadioField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    weight = IntegerField('Weight', validators=[DataRequired()])

class EntryForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Entry Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    games = FieldList(FormField(PickForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate(self):
        if not super(EntryForm, self).validate():
            return False
        result = True
        seen = set()
        for pick in self.games:
            if (pick.weight.data in seen and
                    pick.weight.data <= len(self.games)):
                pick.errors.append('Please rank reach pick from 1 to {} with no repeats.'.format(len(self.games)))
                result = False
            else:
                seen.add(pick.weight.data)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being I was appending entries onto `form.games` on both the GET and POST requests, resulting in a list twice the size I wanted with the top half not populated. A little more logic to check the current length of `form.games` before appending an entry got around this. This may not be the most elegant possible way of dynamically adding these fields, but it works for now and is a lot better than the previous way I was doing it!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not accessing form.games correctly. I think you need to use: form.games.entries

As explained in docs: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#field-enclosures

Sorry about crappy formatting. I am on cellphone but still want to get points.